# How to get the link after uploading to Google Drive via api in python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Here am using google drive API with python to upload files to google drive, how can I get the link of the uploaded file.

I tried `print (res['exportLinks'])`, but it gives me this error.

> KeyError: 'exportLinks'

Complete python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILES = (('hello.txt', False),)

for filename, convert in FILES:
    metadata = {'title': filename}
    res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
            media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
    if res:
        print (res['exportLinks'])
```

Is there any alternate way to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `KeyError: 'exportLinks'` means there is no key 'exportLinks'. Try printing `type(res)` and `res.keys()` if its a dictionary.

Comment: res.keys() gives: ([u'mimeType'])

Comment: can you please add the result of `print(res)` to your question ? this is the first time I'm seeing `apiclient` but I figure you can `import json` and `json.dumps(res)`

Comment: change the fields to `*` and the version from v2 to v3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/folder), it says you can get the id of the uploaded file by calling `file.get('id')` - that is `res.get('id')` in your case.

try this code

```
    # ...
    res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
        media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks,id').execute() # <-- EDIT: added id here
    print('Uploaded file to {url}'.format(url='https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + res.get('id')))
```

Comment: res.get('id') returns None

Comment: was the file uploaded though ? it would make sense to return `None` if no file was uploaded

Comment: @Sumithran aha I think I got it, you have to add the `id` to `fields` of your `.execute()`, see my edited answer in a sec

Comment: Is this link sharable? I mean it is allowed for EVERYONE to use this link to open the file?